# Convertir imagen a color indexado en java

Tags: java, imagen, bufferedimage

Tengo una imagen almacenada en un `BufferedImage` en color `RGB` (aunque bien podría ser otro) y necesito convertirla a color `indexado` con `Java`.

Alguna idea de cómo lograr esto? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Adriana entiendo tienes  BufferedImage(RGB) , pero a que te refieres con color indexado, podrías agregar más detalles a tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, gracias por la atención. Necesito la imagen con el modelo de color indexado (o sea no en el modelo RGB, sino indexado), lo necesito para ahorrarme espacio en tamaño de imágenes, sobre todo cuando trabajo con muchas... ya que las imágenes indexadas reducen su tamaño considerablemente al crear índices para los colores de los píxeles y añadiendo punteros hacia un índice cuando se repite un color, en vez de repetir dicho color. Y para ser más específica, con color indexado me refiero a [esto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color)

Comment: No lo doy como respuesta, porque no es la respuesta que esperas, solo quiero agregar que en java directamente no hay muchos framework o elementos de programacion que manipulen imagenes sin tener que bajar a C++, en este caso open cv tiene una solucion segun este post http://code.opencv.org/issues/2863 y hay un wrapper de open cv para java aqui http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he logrado hacer con la ayuda de [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613520/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-indexed-type-and-then-extract-the-argb-color-pal) código. Muchas gracias al usuario Jorge, me sirvió de mucho:

```
public static BufferedImage rgbaToIndexedBufferedImage(BufferedImage sourceBufferedImage) {
    //With this constructor we create an indexed bufferedimage with the same dimensiosn and with a default 256 color model
    BufferedImage indexedImage= new BufferedImage(sourceBufferedImage.getWidth(),sourceBufferedImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);


    ColorModel cm = indexedImage.getColorModel();
    IndexColorModel icm=(IndexColorModel) cm;

    int size=icm.getMapSize();

    byte[] reds = new byte[size];
    byte[] greens = new byte[size];
    byte[] blues = new byte[size];
    icm.getReds(reds);
    icm.getGreens(greens);
    icm.getBlues(blues);

    WritableRaster raster=indexedImage.getRaster();
    int pixel = raster.getSample(0, 0, 0); 
    IndexColorModel icm2 = new IndexColorModel(8, size, reds, greens, blues,pixel);
    indexedImage=new BufferedImage(icm2, raster,sourceBufferedImage.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    indexedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceBufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
    return indexedImage;
}
```

Comment: cuando puedas marca esta respuesta como correcta,  saludos! :)